# Caps lock key to behave like non-toggle modifier

Tags: keyboard, keybindings, caps-lock, karabiner

Is it possible to make the caps lock key behave like a normal modifier, and not as a toggle switch?

I have a custom keyboard layout which allows me to use the caps lock key to type Greek symbols. (It‘s useful for STEM students.) Most of the time, I only want to type a single Greek symbol—in which case, it would be much easier to use the caps lock key like one uses the shift key. Caps lock down, press a key, then caps lock up—caps lock does not remain on.

Is this possible to accomplish? Perhaps with Karabiner or similar?

Comment: Have you considered using the Option level instead of Caps Lock for the needed symbols?

Comment: I already use the option key for symbols: accents and extended punctuation, etc. I could use a dead key to put the keyboard in “Greek mode” when a special key is pressed, but I’m trying to avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

The easy method of using Apple system preferences only allows mapping the caps lock key to modifier keys and escape key.

[Can't swap Caps Lock and Esc keys using Seil](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/207475/)

[Use caps-lock to lock fn key or other way to lock fn key?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/235965/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is entirely possible with [Karabiner Elements](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/).

The best way to do it is to use Karabiner-Elements to map <kbd>caps lock</kbd> to something like <kbd>shift-control-option-command</kbd> and then have <kbd>shift-control-option-command</kbd> and something else such as <kbd>a</kbd> as a keyboard shortcut for your Greek character.

Comment: Unfortunately, this hack means you cannot use `caps` with another modifier (e.g., `shift`) to, for instance, type shifted (upper case) Greek characters. (Currently, my keyboard maps `caps` to the lower Greek alphabet, `caps + shift` to capital Greek alphabets, and even `caps + alt` and `caps + alt + shift` to lower and upper letter form variants.)